# Angular ng-if specific route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to show a div if view is a certain route. I have a universal header and footer but there is one thing on the header I don't want to show on my / route.

```
<body>     
  <header>
  <section ng-if=""></section>
  </header>

  <div ng-view class="view">

  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leverage [$routeChangeSuccess](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route#events_%24routechangesuccess). Something like this should work (not tested):

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
      $rootScope.showSection = $location.path() !== "/";
  });
});
```

and then...

```
<body>     
  <header>
  <section ng-if="showSection"></section>
  </header>

  <div ng-view class="view">

  <footer></footer>
</body>
```